# Cancel WaitCommEvent for overlapped serial I/O

Tags: windows, serial-port, modem, handshake, overlapped-io

I'm handling a non-standard modem via **serial port in an overlapped** manner. Besides reading from and writing to the telecommunication line, I have to check the control lines like **CTS** and **DSR** using the [`WaitCommEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
DWORD EvtMask;
/// (some scopes/levels ommitted)

const BOOL syncChange = WaitComEvent(hFile, &EvtMask, &overlapped);
if (!syncChange) {
    assert(GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING);
    /// *background activity* probably writing into EvtMask
    /// until overlapped.hEvent gets signalled
}
```

In the (practically all) cases the function call indicates `*background activity*`, I have to wait on the `overlapped.hEvent` to happen. Since I'm also waiting for events from alternative sources (like IPC caused by user input, program termination), I use the `WaitForMuiltipleObjects()` function. But, if the blocking wait is finished for **other reasons than control line changes**, how can I stop the background activity on `EvtMask`? The code I'm based on, currently uses `SetCommMask(hFile, 0)`, but I did not find a reliable reference for this being appropriate.

I also observe cases where changes to control lines are not supported properly (driver?, VM?), so I have to do a *sliced wait* with in-between checking.

**What must be done to safely leave the scope where the variable `EvtMask` is declared?**

Comment: You have to call CancelIo().  User input is not normally a great reason to cancel I/O of course.  You got a Chinese fortune cookie that says you are going to rewrite this completely.

Comment: @HansPassant haha, there's a whole lot to rewrite...

Comment: @HansPassant I changed the question, there is another (important) reason to be considered. Does it now make more sense to you? Thanks!

Comment: @Hans: No, you don't.

Comment: @BenVoigt so this question seems valid from you POV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is correct, and fully supported by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363479.aspx), which clearly says:

> If a process attempts to change the device handle's event mask by using the `SetCommMask` function while an overlapped `WaitCommEvent` operation is in progress, `WaitCommEvent` returns immediately.

I've used this fact on both "real" serial ports, and USB virtual serial port emulations, and it works reliably.

(In my particular case, I was watching for `EV_TXEMPTY` so that I could guarantee a minimal separation between certain transmissions *on the wire*)

Comment: Nice, this very portion was *not* clear to me. It mixes WaitCommEvent-calls and the operation started in background. Nevertheless thanks for having a look at it. And it's definitely helpful :-)

Comment: Just a tiny detail: after calling `SetCommMask` with the zero mask, have you to call `WaitCommEvent` once more?

Comment: @Wolf: The pending `WaitCommEvent` operation will complete immediately (or at least, very soon -- don't assume you have your memory back as soon as `SetCommMask` is called).  So if you want notifications once more, you have to call it once more.

Comment: If I use a zero mask, then there will be probably no real notifications. But it seems likely that the variable I used in the `WaitCommEvent` call is still bound. Don't I have to call `GetOverlappedResult(..., TRUE)`?

Comment: @Wolf: You should handle a forced completion the same way you handle any other.  Call `GetOverlappedResult` and if you are still interested in events, call `WaitCommEvent` again, otherwise you can do away with the memory.